# How to continue a list on the second level

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am instructed to write a document with lists and some standard (or otherwisely) formatted text between list items, also between list items on the second level of a list. I tried naming the `series` on the second level, but that doesn't help, as the third part of the list below would just resume on the first level. See comments in the code. Preamble provided for your convenience.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first of first
        \item second of first
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} % all is well

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[resume] % this resumes the list on the first level as intended
    \item second
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first of second
        \item second of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[42]

\begin{enumerate}[resume] % I'd like the list to resume on the second level
    \item third of second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What I have tried so far (and didn't work for me):

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item third of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

---

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item second
    \begin{enumerate}[series=mylist]
        \item first of second
        \item second of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

and then some text to fill the gaps 

\begin{enumerate}[resume=mylist]
    \item third of second
\end{enumerate}
```

---

```
some other screwed up chaotic things ;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the first level, at least with an empty label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first of first
        \item second of first
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} % all is well

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[resume] % this resumes the list on the first level as intended
    \item second \label{enum:second}
    \begin{enumerate}[series=mylist]
        \item first of second 
        \item second of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[42]

\begin{enumerate} % I'd like the list to resume on the second level
 \item[\ref{enum:second}.\rlap{ (cont.)}]~
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=mylist]
     \item third of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

some text 
\begin{enumerate} % I'd like the list to resume on the second level
 \item[]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=mylist]
     \item fourth of second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]